# How to check if website name provided is available and free in Azure SDK for dot net

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

I'm trying to create a web app in azure using

```
azure.WebApps
.Define(name)
.WithExistingWindowsPlan(plan) 
.WithExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroupName)
.CreateAsyn()
```

Since the name must be globally unique, how can I check if the name exist already?

Comment: Catch the error and handle it?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Erndob's comment there - I'll extend it by saying that catch the error and look into the specifics. If it's failing with a `name not unique` error - that's your check failing right there. Any other failures should be treated differently.

Comment: @Dzior I'd appreciate the green tick if this qualifies as the answer.